# How to map through an Array of object with the same data on some object and get it displayed once and also get other properties

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have an array of products like this coming from firebase,

```
products: [
  {
    id: "product_1", 
    drinkName: "Chivita", 
    category: "Juice", 
    description: "The best drink ever"
  },
  {
    id: "product_2", 
    drinkName: "5 Alive", 
    category: "Juice", 
    description: "The best drink ever"
  },
  {
    id: "product_3", 
    drinkName: "Cocacola", 
    category: "Others", 
    description: "The best drink ever"
  }
];
```

What I want is to `loop` through the array and get the category displayed only once, I know each drink can have the same category, but I want it displayed only once and also get its Id for each product, and also get the `drinkName` display under each category. The id will be used to navigate to the `Product Details page`.

I already have something like this:

```
const items = products?.reduce((prev, current) => {
    if (!(current?.data()?.category in prev)) {
      prev[current?.data()?.category] = [];
    }
    prev[current?.data()?.category].push({
      drinkName: current?.data()?.drinkName,
      id: current.id,
    });
    return prev;
  }, {});
```

Error 1: `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type '{}'.`

This Error shows where `prev[current?.data()?.category]`

Now time to loop

```
 {Object.keys(items).map((key: any) => {
   return (
       <AccordionItem key={key.id}>
         <h2>
         <AccordionButton fontSize={"sm"} fontWeight={"medium"}>
         <Box flex="1" textAlign="left">
           {key}
         </Box>
         <AccordionIcon />
         </AccordionButton>
         </h2>
         <AccordionPanel px={0} pb={4}>
           {items.map((drinkName: any, idx: number) => {
             return (
              <Flex key={idx}>
                 <Button
                   size={"sm"}
                   variant={"ghost"}
                   fontWeight={"light"}
                 >
                  {drinkName}
                </Button>
              </Flex>
          );
      })};
```

So, when I loop through the first time, grab the category and id, if the category exists already, display it once because multiple drinks can have the same category.

The second time, grab the drinkName and pass the id to the button when clicked navigate to the product details [which is simple].

Error 2:

```
{items.map((drinkName: any, idx: number) => {
                 return (
                  <Flex key={idx}>
                     <Button
                       size={"sm"}
                       variant={"ghost"}
                       fontWeight={"light"}
                     >
                      {drinkName}
                    </Button>
                  </Flex>
              )

Objects are not valid as a React child. If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead
```

When I do

```
console.log(items)
```

[image]

When I do

```
{Object.keys(items[key]).map((drinkObject: any, idx: number) => {
               
                console.log(drinkObject);
             // Prints the indexes on the drink: e.g if Juice is a category, I will have 0, 1, 2 based on the items there
          })}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple issues, so let me break it down a bit.

So I ran down and relooked over the code, I understand you're doing things a bit differently than expected now. So, the same as before, the type of `}, {});` is an empty object. TS cannot understand that you're trying to access [current?.data().category] at runtime. You would need to make it either strongly typed, or get away with using {unknown}, which could make sense and might suppress the issue.

I suspect you could use this instead:

```
return prev
}, 
({} as {[key: string]: Array<{category?: string, drinkName: string, id: string}>}))
```

In the second issue, the same that I said before this edit is true. You are using items.map on an object. You probably want it Object.keys like above.

Comment: Also as I noted in an old edit, you should get used to using less ": any" and make return types on functions. Both are great to get the full extent of TS. It may be beneficial to use the react "useMemo" hook to get some performance benefits out of this. I suspect products can be quite large.

Comment: Thank you very much, For the second one, when I do object.keys(items[key].map), 

I get the Array indexes, like for each category, 0, 1.... 0, 1,2... Based on the items

Comment: I want to get the drinkName and id, like how it's printed... Let me update the question

Comment: I think you actually want to do key.map(el => etc...). Think about what is actually happening in these array methods, you're just doing foreach loops with some side-effects. So what you're wanting is to loop through the items in the inside arrays, which is the key in your object.keys. If you remove your unnecessary : any 's you could get better intellisense and understand what's inside each property.

Comment: When I removed any, from drinkName, I got string;

Comment: https://ibb.co/JKJct09

Comment: Can you post full code as an answer, please